# Don't check face Id scan in local_auth package flutter

Tags: android, flutter, biometrics, android-biometric, localauthentication

How to disable face Id scan in local_auth flutter for Android. Athenticate with only fingerprint. Or can i do it on native Android side

On android settings if registered FaceID and Fingerprint by default it's check faceid but i won't use only fingerprint

Answer (score 0):

```
In Authentication Option you will get all option please check once 


     authenticated = await auth.authenticate(
    localizedReason:
        'Scan your fingerprint (or face or whatever) to authenticate',
      options: const AuthenticationOptions(       
        biometricOnly: false,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).